# How to sum dataframe in pandas for more than 5

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

in my days column if my  number is more than 5 I want to sum that column

Input:

```
Days  files 
1      10
3      20
4      30
5      40
6      50
```

Required output:

```
Days  files 
1      10
3      20
4      30
5+     90
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try `series.clip` to clip the upperbound in the series , then do a groupby and sum:

```
out = df['files'].groupby(df['Days'].clip(upper=5)).sum().reset_index()
print(out)

  Days  files
0    1     10
1    3     20
2    4     30
3    5     90
```

If you really want to change anything above 5 into a str type , you can jst replace the `5` using the above logic:

```
out = df['files'].groupby(df['Days'].clip(upper=5).replace(5,'5+')).sum().reset_index()
print(out)

  Days  files
0    1     10
1    3     20
2    4     30
3   5+     90
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
above = df.files[df.Days >= 5].sum()
df[df.Days < 5].append({'Days': '5+', 'files': above}, ignore_index=True)
```

It gives:

```
  Days  files
0    1     10
1    3     20
2    4     30
3   5+     90
```